# Kali Linux 2.0 stopped update proccess

Tags: linux, upgrade, kali-linux

So I decided to update my Kali Linux to 2.0 using the dist-upgrade command and obviously having the official mirrors from the Kali website. It was over a GB of data that needed to be downloaded, so I waited for it to finish. When the downloading part finished it started unpacking and installing the files It just downloaded, but I then accidentally stopped the process and that was it. I didn't want to download everything again so I just rebooted the laptop.

Now I am running Kali Sana and it is working smoothly and everything "seems" to be fine at the moment. I just wanted to know if the fact that i stopped the process will affect how Kali will run in the future. And if it will affect it, please tell me what i should do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade process is very careful about what it does and how it writes files to disk, so your installation should be OK (depending on how exactly you stopped the process...). There may be some outstanding configuration tasks waiting, and some packages may be out of sync, so you should still finish the upgrade; this won't re-download everything, anything that's already been downloaded will still be in your package cache.

To finish the installation, just rerun

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you want to finish the outstanding configuration first, run

```
dpkg --configure --pending
```

(both commands as `root`).

Comment: I have already done the dist-upgrade command and it says: 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.        

but with the dpkg command it does nothing and just says root@kali on a new line.

does it mean that everything is ok?

Comment: OK, that means your first upgrade actually completed.